# mysql stuck at query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database of a college. I am stuck and don't understand a query that I have to write. I have to retrieve names of instructors teaching Computer Science courses, the sections, course number, section number, year, and semester that they are teaching, and the total number of students in the sections. 
I am not sure what the output should be like.
So far I have written:

```
SELECT i.name,t.number,t.year,t.semester,t.section_number FROM Instructor as i,Teaches as t WHERE i.department LIKE '%Computer Science%'; 

create table Course (
  number int,
  title varchar(255),
  credits int,
  syllabus varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (number)
  );

INSERT INTO Course VALUES (620,'Algorithm',3,'XYZ');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (621,'Algorithm',3,'XYZ');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (232,'Java',2,'ABC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (420,'Cpp',2,'PQRS');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (720,'Big Data',3,'NVGY');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (120,'Intelligent System',4,'KJHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (220,'Operating System',3,'GED');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (480,'Graphics',4,'RSFN');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (520,'Distributed Networks',3,'NHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (820,'Data Mining',3,'TYU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (700,'Cryptography',1,'MNO');

create table Student (
  student_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (2345,'Mike','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (346,'Rob','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (789,'Nick','Game Design');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (675,'Sara','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (123,'Raj','Chemical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (5331,'Jack','Biotech');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1023,'Michelle','Chemical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (9800,'Jie','Game Design');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (7834,'Dan','Petroleum');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (4567,'Patrick','Computer Science');


create table Instructor (
  instructor_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  title varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (12,'John','Computer Science','Java');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (23,'Bischof','Mechanical','Drawing');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (56,'Kwon','Biotech','Biology');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (78,'Deever','Security','Cryptography');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (45,'Jin','Computer Science','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (67,'Bailey','Petroleum','Metalurgy');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (90,'Richard','Industrial','Manufacture');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (11,'Joe','Chemical','Chemistry');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (24,'Roger','Game Design','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (55,'Zack','Computer Science','Design');


create table CourseOffering (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  classroom int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (620,2012,2,102,3540);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (621,2013,3,103,3545);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2650);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (720,2013,3,100,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (120,2014,1,102,3000);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (220,2008,2,104,1450);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (480,2009,4,106,1400);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (520,2010,3,102,3500);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2700);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (700,2012,1,103,2540);

create table CourseOffering_Timing (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  timing int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number,timing),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (620,2012,2,102,9);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (621,2013,3,103,9);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (720,2013,3,100,5);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (120,2014,1,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (220,2008,2,104,10);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (480,2009,4,106,12);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (520,2010,3,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (700,2012,1,103,3);

create table PreRequisite (
  number int,
  prerequisite_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,prerequisite_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course(number)
  );

INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (620,480);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (621,481);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (232,120);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (420,320);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (720,580);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (120,110);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (220,130);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (480,380);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (520,360);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (820,700);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (700,610);


create table enrolls (
  student_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  grade varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id,number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number,year,semester,section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering(number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student (student_id)  
  );

INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (2345,620,2012,2,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (346,232,2011,1,103,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (789,420,2013,3,101,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (675,621,2013,3,103,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (123,120,2014,1,102,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (5331,220,2008,2,104,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (1023,480,2009,4,106,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (9800,520,2010,3,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (7834,820,2008,3,100,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (4567,700,2012,1,103,'F');

create table teaches (
  instructor_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id, number, year, semester, section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id) REFERENCES Instructor(instructor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY ( number, year, semester, section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering( number, year, semester, section_number)
  );



INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (12,620,2012,2,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (12,621,2013,3,103);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (23,232,2011,1,103);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (56,420,2013,3,101);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (78,720,2013,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (45,120,2014,1,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (67,220,2008,2,104);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (90,480,2009,4,106);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (11,520,2010,3,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (24,820,2008,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (55,700,2012,1,103);
```

Comment: Read up on SQL JOIN.  You need to join multiple tables together to get your answer.

Comment: And note that line breaks are allowed, also within `SELECT` statements.

Comment: codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about `JOIN` clauses in SQL.

You might also find http://sqlfiddle.com/ to be a useful tool.

Here's an example query.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aca1a/7/0

```
SELECT i.name,t.number,
       c.title,
       t.year,t.semester,t.section_number 
  FROM Instructor as i
  JOIN Teaches as t USING(instructor_id)
  JOIN Course as c USING(number)
 WHERE i.department LIKE '%Computer Science%';
```

Do you see how the various id numbers in various tables can be used to attach records from one table to the next?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT i.name,t.number,      
       t.year,t.semester,t.section_number,COUNT(c.student_id)as TotalStudents
  FROM Instructor as i
  JOIN Teaches as t USING(instructor_id)
  JOIN enrolls as c  
 WHERE i.department LIKE '%Computer Science%' AND c.number=t.number ;